# different resolutions vs dpi

Tags: android, resolution, dpi

I would like to get advice, pros and cons, about using different resolution graphics or resize them with dip size.

I mean, if my ap will have all possible resolution, one way is to create the pngs for each one, ldp/mdp/hdp/xhdp, but I am thinking that to save work and time maintaining the app, maybe is easier, to include pngs with maximal resolution, xhdp, and to specify the size well in the .xml or in the .java with dip or relative size depending on the screen.

What is your opinion on that? Pros and Cons?

Regards,

Comment: I am not an expert on mobile programming but creating pngs multiple times with different resolution seems unnecessary. At the end, scaling down is not a disadvantage.

Comment: @MertToka Android expects images in different resolutions. There are different directories for that job. But you are right this makes not sense in every case.

Comment: This is what I think. But as there are different folders for different resolution files in the sdk I am doing like that. However, my app have about 200 graphics files and I have to have 4 different resolutions for each file what means a hard job. I can avoid this just by code or layout definition.

Comment: What do you think it is a better practice, to define a size by "x dp" in the layout or by code in java?

Comment: So far I know Android detects that and converts the images to the right resolution, but this maybe not so performance and/or the images maybe not so nice scalled down like if you do that manually. I beleve that dip (device independed pixels) are the best choise, but I have not proof for that!

Answer (score 0):

Cons (against having only one size): Unnecessary use of memory. 
Images are memory-hungry objects, and when you multiply its resolution twice you multiply its memory cost by 4. 
Low-resolution devices are likely to have less memory as well and loading unnecessary big images could cause memory exceptions.